# Is UDP a reliable protocol for IPC?

Tags: sockets, udp, ipc

If I use UDP purely for inter-process communication (i.e., in 1 system, **with no network involved**), can I consider it to be reliable? Or do I still need to worry about packets getting dropped, etc.?

**Note** that this is a *practical* question, not a theoretical one. If the answer differs across OSes, please explain how, in particular including Windows, Linux, and Mac.

---

#### Edit: Nope, it's not reliable -- example below.

Thanks to the current answer for pointing me in the right direction.
This code drops a packet on Windows 8.1 (I get `Received: 18432 (DROPPED PACKET)`).
(I'm not sure why it doesn't run on Linux, but it should be close to working.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#endif

int main()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    typedef int socklen_t;
#else
    typedef int SOCKET;
#endif
    SOCKET r = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr = { AF_INET };
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7F000001);
    {
        socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        if (bind(r, (struct sockaddr *)(&addr), addrlen) == -1 ||
            getsockname(r, (struct sockaddr *)(&addr), &addrlen) == -1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    int tids = 0;
    for (long c = 0, i = 0, j = 0; c < 1000000; ++c)
    {
        if ((c + 1) % 10)
        {
            int n = sendto(s, (char const *)(&i), sizeof(i), 0, (struct sockaddr const *)(&addr), sizeof(addr));
            if (n != sizeof(i)) { return 1; }
            // else { fprintf(stderr, "Sent:     %lu\n", i); }
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            struct sockaddr temp;
            socklen_t templen = sizeof(temp);
            long v;
            int n = recvfrom(r, (char *)(&v), sizeof(v), 0, (struct sockaddr *)(&temp), &templen);
            if (n != sizeof(v)) { return 2; }
            else if (v != j) { fprintf(stderr, "Received: %lu (DROPPED PACKET)\n", v); return 3; }
            // else { fprintf(stderr, "Received: %lu\n", v); }
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't a reliable protocol for anything.

Comment: @EJP: You've observed it drop packets locally?

Comment: @Mehrdad I have observed what it says in the RFC and the absence of acknowledgment and retry from the protocol. QED. No empirical  observation necessary.

Comment: @EJP: I was *quite explicitly* stating that I'm asking a practical question, not a theoretical one. i.e., I'm looking for an empirical observation, not an axiomatic one. So yes, it is necessary because **that's what I'm *asking***.

Comment: What is the practical problem that you are trying to solve...... it's like Tycho Brahe vs Johannes Kepler....

Comment: @CristiFati: I'm trying to learn? Not sure what you mean by the comparison either. I'm not asking anyone compare anything with UDP.

Comment: I will state again and despite whoever is deleting my correct statements that it is unscientific to look for anecdotal evidence about a formal behaviour. The answer is in the RFC, or it isn't, and it isn't, so there is no reliability. You can't rely on empirical observation alone.  UDP has required behaviour, and reliability isn't part of it.

Comment: Reproducible on _Ux_ too. Built on _RH7_ (had to move some of the declarations at the beginning of the block to be C99 compliant), using _gcc-4.8.2_, and noticed the packet drop at runtime.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If I use UDP purely for inter-process communication (i.e., in 1
>   system, with no network involved), can I consider it to be reliable?

No.  UDP packets can (and sometimes will) still be dropped even when all communication is being done over the same host.

You can demonstrate this for yourself, if you want; set up two UDP-socket-using programs on the same host, with program A sending UDP packets to program B that receives them and records them.  (Include sequence numbers in the UDP packets so that program B can easily tell when a packet was not received).

Once that is working and packets are being transmitted at a decent rate, put some code into program B so that every so often it calls sleep(5) (or similar, so that program B fails to call recv() on its UDP socket for a significant amount of time).  You'll likely see that after the sleep() call returns, program B reports that some packets were skipped -- because while B was asleep, the incoming-packets buffer for its UDP socket became full and then some packets were dropped by the networking stack because there was no place to put them.

Comment: Interesting. Which OSes have you observed this behavior in?

Comment: All of them. You don't need to obserc

Comment: @Mehrdad you'll see it under any OS.  It's a natural outcome of the fact that RAM space is limited, so only a finite number of UDP packets can be stored (awaiting processing by the receiving application) at one time.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Well, I'm asking because the last time I tried something similar on Windows, it didn't run into any queue size limits -- it happily kept sending packets until the system ran of memory. I'm asking which OSes **you've** seen it happen on, so please answer that. Have you *actually* seen it happen? Or is this just a hypothesis?

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm pretty sure I've seen it under Windows, but to be 100% certain I set up a test just now on my Windows 7 machine and verified that Windows 7 does indeed behave as I described.  The only time I've seen behavior like what you described in your comment is when the receiving program has a separate I/O thread whose job is to allocate a RAM buffer, recv() the packet data into it, and then add that buffer to a FIFO data structure for the main thread to process later -- in that case, if the main thread gets stuck somehow, the FIFO will grow without bound and eventually exhaust all RAM.

Comment: Note also that Windows documentation of the SO_RCVBUF setsockopt() parameter strongly implies that a socket's receive buffer is fixed-size under Windows (otherwise it would not make sense to allow the user to set the size of the buffer):  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Thanks for looking into it. Indeed, I did have an I/O completion port being processed on a separate thread, so that may have been why I never saw any packet drops. Just to confirm a crucial point regarding your scenario: when the packet is dropped, do you not get any errors whatsoever? i.e., to the sender, does it look like it succeeded, but then later gets dropped silently? Or do you get an error (such as `ENOBUFS`/`WSAENOBUFS`)?

Comment: @Mehrdad: packets get dropped at the OS layer before they reach the target application. There is no indication given to either application that packets have been dropped (unless the loss is due to network connectively issues, in which case the sender *might* receive an error). That is why UDP-based protocols tend to include sequence numbers in the packet data so applications can discover when packets have been lost, or received out of order.

Comment: P.S. @JeremyFriesner I just tried this on Linux and I didn't lose any packets there either. Unless something is specific to my system or test (which is possible -- I'll try to look into it), I'm not observing what you're saying here either. (I'll try it on Windows without IOCP too when I get the chance, but I might not very soon.)

Comment: @Mehrdad No error is reported (that I'm aware of).  If you're not seeing dropped packets in your test, try sending packets more often, sending larger packets, making the receiving program sleep for a longer period of time, or reducing the receiver's receive-buffer size via setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF).  (Any of those should make the receiver's buffer more likely to overflow)

Comment: Ahh, finally managed to drop a packet! Edited the code into my question. Thanks for the answer!!