# Is internal udp lossless?

Tags: tcp, udp

I use a lot of internal tcp for ipc. My question is for use between processes on the same system, can udp still loose packets, and if so why/how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is UDP a reliable protocol for IPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338588/is-udp-a-reliable-protocol-for-ipc)

Comment: Well i know of rudp and im not saying for ipc that was an example of what ive done with tcp. Im asking if internal udp is lossless

Comment: But that thread does seem to answer my question...