# Qt: why is QUdp socket not receiving datagram?

Tags: c++, qt, udp, ipc

When I open myapp, I check tasklist.exe for other instances of myapp. If there is another one, I want to send a message from the second instance to the first instance. I am using a QUdpSocket to do this. However, the second never seems to  reach readPendingDatagrams(), even though I call writeDatagram(). Why?

```
void MainWindow::readPendingDatagrams(){
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QNetworkDatagram datagram(udpSocket->receiveDatagram());
        qDebug() << "datagram: " << datagram.data();
    }
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent){

    qDebug() << "processid: " << QCoreApplication::applicationPid();

    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket;
    connect(udpSocket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::readPendingDatagrams);
    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 7755);

    QProcess process;
    process.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    process.start("tasklist.exe");
    process.waitForStarted(1000);
    process.waitForFinished(1000);

    QString taskList = process.readAll();

    if (taskList.count("myapp") > 1){
        QByteArray data;
        data.append("Hello from processid: ");
        data.append(QString::number(QCoreApplication::applicationPid()));
        udpSocket->writeDatagram(data, QHostAddress::LocalHost, 7755);          
    }
}
```

Also, is this robust?

Comment: If by "is this robust?", you are asking if the UDP packet is guaranteed to be delivered, the answer is no.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338588/is-udp-a-reliable-protocol-for-ipc/39338991#39338991

Comment: Is your app actually name `myapp` (ie. are you able to find that string if you run your app and then manually check the return of tasklist.exe command?) Your code works fine for me (the only change I made is to use the default app name there).